# Cassandra: rotating lists

Tags: cassandra

Suppose I store a list of events in a Cassandra row, implemented with composite columns:

```
{
    event:123 => 'something happened'
    event:234 => 'something else happened'
}
```

It's almost fine by me, and, as far as I understand, that's a common pattern. Comparing to having a single column `event` with the jsonized list, that scales better since it's easy to add a new item to the list without reading it first and then writing back.

However, now I need to implement these two requirements:

- I don't want to add a new event if the last added one is the same,
- I want to keep only N last events.

Is there any standard way of doing that with the best possible performance? (Any storage schema changes are ok).

Comment: Not a real answer, but for your first point, is there some unique identifier you could use as part of the _key_, so that the same events get the same key? That'd save you a read->write cycle. For your second point, must it be the last N, or can it be the ones within a specified time window? If the time window works, you could apply a TTL to your rows so they die after a while.

Comment: @MyseriousDan for the unique key, unfortunately, that will not allow to trace event sequences like "A->B->A->B" (they'll look like "A->B"). And for TTL, I need to ensure that at least N last events are kept indefinitely long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking whether or not things already exist, or checking how many that exist and removing extra items, are both read-modify-write operations, and they don't fit very well with the constraints of Cassandra.

One way of keeping only the N last events is to make sure they are ordered so that you can do a range query and read the N last (for example prefixing the column key with a timestamp/TimeUUID). This wouldn't remove the outdated events, that you need to do as a separate process, but by doing it this way the code that queries the data will only see the last N, which is the real requirement if I interpret things correctly. The garbage collection of old events is just an optimization to avoid keeping things that will never be needed again.

If the requirement isn't a strict N events, but events that are not older than T you can of course use the TTL feature, but I assume that it's not an option for you.

The first requirement is trickier. You can do a read before ever write and check if you have an item, but that would be slow, and unless you do some kind of locking outside of Cassandra there is no guarantee that two writers won't do both do a read and then both do a write, so that neither sees the other's write. Maybe that's not a problem for you, but there's no good way around it. Cassandra doesn't do CAS.

The way I've handled similar situations when using Cassandra is to keep a cache in the application nodes of what has been written, and check that before writing. You then need to make sure that each application node sees all events for the same row, and that events for the same row aren't distributed over multiple application nodes. One way of doing that is to have a message queue system in front of your application nodes, and divide the event stream over several queues by the same key as you use as row key in the database.

Comment: Actually, it now seems that I defined the requirements on a bit too low level. What I really need, is to keep a sequence of events, but for space-preserving purposes we need to keep only last N, but TTL is unfortunately not an option. Also, the external systems reporting events may re-send the same event multiple times with different timestamps, and we don't want to waste space for those duplicates.

Comment: So how are you identifying "duplicates"? Is it purely by the string message?

Comment: @MyseriousDan yep, just a string message. For now we decided to keep using the original `[event;timestamp]=>value` approach, clean the old garbage by some batch job if it's needed and cache events in the apps.